Why doesn't this while loop start when the tkinter button is pressed?
I have a basic python speech to text transcriber. I wanted to wrap it in some simple GUI just for fun, but having a lot of trouble trying to add a stop and start button to this. Would appreciate some guidance!
I thought if I added a button to set the value the while function is dependent on that it would be able to start and stop the function, however, that doesn't seem to work. Nothing happens at all.
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import tkinter as tk

r = sr.Recognizer()

def start(value):
    global startCheck
    startCheck = 0
    variable = value

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("CrittyCorder")
root.geometry("500x500")

label = tk.Label(root, text="Critty Corder", font=('Arial',24))
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

buttonframe = tk.Frame(root)
buttonframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
buttonframe.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
buttonframe.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

startbutton = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Start 'cording", font=('Arial',18),command=lambda *args: start(1))
startbutton.grid(row=0, column=0)
stopbutton = tk.Button(buttonframe, text="Stop 'cording", font=('Arial',18),command=lambda *args: start(0))
stopbutton.grid(row=0, column=1)

buttonframe.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()

def record_text():
    while(1):
        try:
            with sr.Microphone() as source2:
                r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source2, duration=0.2)
                audio2 = r.listen(source2)

                MyText = r.recognize_google(audio2)

                return MyText

        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("Couldn't get results; {0}".format(e))

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Unkown error occured")

    return

def output_text(text):
    f = open("critvoice.txt", "r")
    temp = f.read()
    f.close()
    f = open("critvoice.txt", "w")
    f.seek(0,0)
    f.write(text + '\n' + temp)
    f.write("\n")
    f.close()

    return

while(startCheck == 1):
    text = record_text()
    output_text(text)
    print("wrote text:", text)

Is there another way I should be implementing this?

It's not clear which while loop you are talking about. One is inside a function, that is only called inside the other. The other only runs when startCheck==. I don't see any place where startCheck is anything other than zero.

The while after mainloop is never reached. Using while is not recommended, because it will block the main loop from updating. Refactor using after to manage recurring tasks.

As pointed out - while loop was never reached. Messed up a variable. but thankfully my main question of what to do instead of this was also answered - Refactor using after to manage recurring tasks. –
OysterShucker
